# TypeError: Logging is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to import the Google Cloud Logging using the same way specified in https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/#quickstart

But for some reason, I am getting an error "TypeError: Logging is not a constructor".
I even tried adding the projectId but still the same error.

Any ideas what I can try?

```
const { Logging } = require('@google-cloud/logging');
const loggingClient = new Logging();
```

Comment: Though I was unable to identify specific clues as well as sufficient insight of this error here, since the format looks good, can you please check  if you are using the latest version of libraries or not. Similar [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60136446/), though that is for PubSub.You can also  take a look at this document on [Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).Also adding a document for [Setting Up Cloud Logging for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs).

Comment: @Aaron Did you ever figured out this one?  I am having the same issue.  Google Cloud documentation is still suggesting the the same way.